# How to work with nuxeo without the nuxeo-studio

Tags: nuxeo

Is it possible for a long period of evaluation purpose to work without the studio?

This means is there a tutorial on how to design workflow without the studio?

Comment: Please don't cross-post or at least mention the duplicate: http://answers.nuxeo.com/questions/12396/trying-nuxeo-without-nuxeo-studio

Comment: Indeed sorry about that.

Comment: @MaatDeamon Did you find any solution to design workflow without the Studio?Can you share your experience if any

Comment: Sorry, I ended up not using nuxeo and moved on from that type of project

Answer (score 1):

Answer from Alain Escaffre:

> [Nuxeo Studio](https://doc.nuxeo.com/x/pgF9) is useful to build maintenable, easily updatable customization on top of Nuxeo Platform. One should use Nuxeo Studio for implementing specific constraints and rules such as custom forms, custom workflows, triggers using automation module etc.. All of this can be implemented without Studio but requires then much more time (a lot of XML to write) and is much harder to maintain. Nuxeo Studio makes sure you can deploy your business rules on top of the up-coming releases of Nuxeo Platform.